# HDFS delegation token error

Tags: hadoop, hive, token, kerberos

I am trying to run jobs from the `Hadoop` service users like `Spark`, `falcon`, `hive` but when I execute the command from these users it throws an error:

`HDFS delegation token not found in cache` for that user.

Example: I have created a falcon cluster entity using falcon CLI  but when I submit my entity it throws the same error for Falcon user.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue happened during the standby->active transitioning process of the Namenode. The Namenode had not finished tailing the Editlog, which contained information about generating the corresponding token, thus failed to find the token in its local cache.

A possible solution is to let the client side retry the same operation in this scenario. Thus if the Namenode could not find the token during the transition, it can wrap the InvalidToken exception in the RetriableException and ask the client to retry.